# `make -j `nproc`` in the build folder gives : `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.` in ubuntu18.04

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, ubuntu-18.04, openpose

I followed the installation guide and got the result as "Configuring done" in cmake GUI. I did this installation in Ubuntu18.04 local machine/laptop.

Installation guide link: https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation.md#installation

when running "make -j `nproc`" inside the build folder, then getting below error:

`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.`

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: The -j option allows you to specify the (n)umber of (proc)essors to use during compilation. Thus the moniker nproc. Try running make -j 4

Comment: @Aumnayan:    I tried "make -j 4" as well, but still the same error. Even I tried "make" and then again same error. 

FYI: I checked in build folder has "caffe" folder, "CMakeFiles" folder, "CMakeCache.txt" file and "detect_cuda_archs.cu" file.

Please let me know If I am missing anything here.

Comment: @Valiant the error message indicates that there is no Makefile in the directory where you run `make`. Maybe you forgot to run `cmake` first to generate the makefiles for your project? Please also check that the option `-G "Unix makefiles"` is given to `cmake` to make sure it does actually generate makefiles and not for some other build tool.

Comment: @StefanBecker, Yes, I solved this issue. Your answer make sense.